# How do I use AWS in a JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, webpack

I know a lot about AWS but very little about JavaScript, and even less about webpack / npm. I'm trying to call DynamoDB in a JavaScript Vue module that runs in a browser, and I don't know how to reference just the DynamoDB library. Here's my code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb'); //This doesn't work, I get an undefined error below
//var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); //This works, but I get the whole huge awsk-sdk JavaScript library

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10', region: 'us-east-1', accessKeyId: "XXXXX", secretAccessKey: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" });
```

Here's the error:
Cannot read property 'DocumentClient' of undefined

How can I create a requirement for only the DynamoDB JavaScript library, so that my code will be a reasonable download size?

Comment: Check this out (also the Node.js tutorial): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.JavaScript.html

Comment: Can I just stick a <script> tag inside my JavaScript module? I know I can do that if I'm not using webpack / npm, but I'm kind of confused about where I would put my <script tag>.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to make a VUE app, though vue uses javascript it will be different from vanilla. Try following the Node.js tutorial. Edit: Ah I see it looks like you have actually. One moment let me look through this

Comment: This should be what you are looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb

Comment: That seems to be broken. When I try to use it I get this error: Failed to compile.

./node_modules/dynamodb/node_modules/isemail/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/Users/jesse/Projects/Articles/articles/node_modules/dynamodb/node_modules/isemail/lib'

Comment: I now have a bunch of different npm packages that came with the Vue template, or which I've installed - 'dynamodb', 'aws-sdk', 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb', 'dynamodb-doc-client-wrapper', 'dynamodb-doc'. Are there name spaces on these packages? Are they all from AWS, or from third parties? Is it just a matter of trial and error?

Comment: I'm not supper familar with AWS as I tend to stick to firebase, but as for packages in node. It's really a matter of doing an `npm install packagename`, and it will add it to your "package.json". (for vue make sure your cd into the directory with "package.json"), then adding the `require()` in the js file you need to use it. Doing an overall `npm install` can also help clear out some errors.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - I needed to change this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb'); //This doesn't work, I get an undefined error below
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10', region: 'us-east-1', accessKeyId: "XXXXX", secretAccessKey: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" });
```

to this:

```
var DynamoDB = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb'); //This doesn't work, I get an undefined error below
var dynamodb = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10', region: 'us-east-1', accessKeyId: "XXXXX", secretAccessKey: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" });
```

Notice that I've changed the name from AWS to DynamoDB.